# Why can the address bar resolve javascript:?

Tags: javascript, browser

Why can the address bar, anchor and iframe.src resolve `javascript:`, is there any w3c specification about this?

Comment: Are you asking about `javascript:` urls?

Comment: The truth is, you can't always do that. Try it in Firefox, for example.

Comment: Also, this is relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, the W3C doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript (properly called ECMAScript). The HTML specifications are script language-neutral, you'll actually see them give examples in Tcl. During the height of IE's reign it was not uncommon to come across pages that used VBScript instead of JavaScript.

Browsers needed the ability to evaluate script in URIs after it became popular to do this:

```
<a href="javascript: alert('foo');">click me</a>
```

...which serves as an alternative to the DOM events like `onclick`. I *speculate* that this method came before the DOM events were standardised, or maybe it was introduced as a vendor-extension in order to promote lock-in to a particular browser (*a la* `<marquee>` and `<blink>`). But this is just speculation.

Anyway, if the browser supports the evaluation of script when handling a `href=""` attribute then it's a short stretch to extend support to the address bar. The creation of Bookmarklets, I think, was entirely accidental and unintended, but a positive consequence nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "resolve" it exactly, typing "javascript:alert('here');" you can make an alert box come up in some browsers. There is no specification that I am aware of, it is just that some browsers will run javascript on the client side after a page is loaded.

Generally, if you type something to the left of a colon (:) it is a protocol, for example chrome://, http://, sftp://

Also, in chrome you can open a javascript console and enter javascript directly in there rather than the address bar.

Comment: [The 'javascript' resource identifier scheme](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03)